# Pandas merge function run successfully but operation was not performed

Tags: pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframes, the operation was successful but I can't able to see additional columns from the second dataframe.

The code I am using for the operation -

```
transactions.merge(items, how='left', on='item_id')
```

The First dataframe has these columns - 
[transactions dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiSAm.png)

The second dataframe columns - 
[items dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmLZM.png)

After the merge operation, in the output I can't able to see two additional columns( **item_category_id** , **item_name**) from the second dataframe.

Comment: assign it to some variable. `transactions = transactions.merge(items, how='left', on='item_id')`

Comment: I suspect you're editing in a notebook. The answer below explains why you might be experiencing this error.

Comment: @vb_rises ok, it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas always outputs a new DataFrame when you run a function, instead of modifying the existing DF in memory, as you can see in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for the `merge` function.

With this in mind, you should be responsible for always using the updated, transformed DataFrame in subsequent operations. Just assign the result to the existing `transactions` variable, and it will then contain the new DataFrame:

```
transactions = transactions.merge(items, how='left', on='item_id')
```